# Variance explained by each fixed variable linear mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

**When we use R code for a linear mixed model like this: `model=lmer(y~x1+x2+(1|x3),data)`, how can we calculate the variance explained by each fixed variable?**

To solve this problem, I tried my best to search on the internet.
My understanding is the following :

1. After we run the code : `model=lmer(y~x1+x2+(1|x3),data)`, we run the function `summary(model)`, then we get the variance explained by the random effect（namely `rvariance`）.
2. we run function  `anova(model)`, we get the sum of square for each fixed variable; Variance of each fixed variable can be obtained by dividing sum of square into n (the number of observation)  （`fvariance1`, `fvariance2`）.
3. We use function `r.squaredLR` in the MunMIn package to get the whole variance explained by the whole model (`whole_variance`)
4. To calculate variance explained by each fixed variable,  we use this function

   `fixedvaiance1= whole_variance*fvariance1/(rvariance+fvariance1+fvariance2)`

This is my current understanding. Can anyone give some comments about my understanding? If there are problems with this approach, I'd be happy if you could point them out.